# Add Polyline on MapView for OS X app

Tags: macos, overlay, mapkit

I tried to add a polyline to my existing MapView. Multiple iOS tutorials show how it works with an implementation of mapView:viewForOverlay: and with an MKOverlayView as return type. What return type should be used for OS X development, because in the MapKit framework reference I find no MKOverlayView ...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There correct class you need to use in OSX is MKPolylineRenderer

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{
    MKPolylineRenderer *polylineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [NSColor blueColor];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 3.0;
    return polylineView;
}
```